# Is there a way to look at the code and history of a power point presentation slide?

Tags: xml, image, powerpoint

I am trying to find sources such as ip addresses and changes made as a slide is emailed around.
Content type:
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentatio

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can track the source of the changes, but depending on your version of PowerPoint, there is a review button.  Here's a decent article that outlines the feature: http://bookboon.com/blog/2015/11/powerpoint-2013-tracking-changes-2/